# How can I make docker run a command when the working directory changes?

Tags: java, docker, workflow, nodemon

From the docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/06_bind_mounts/) documentation:

```
 docker run -dp 3000:3000 `
 -w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" `
 node:12-alpine `
 sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

> sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev" - the command. We’re [...], if we look in the package.json, we’ll see that the dev script is starting nodemon

This looks incredible for a node.js project, but how can I accomplish the same for my Java project? In a way that, everytime I change something within my working directory, the java files will get compiled again and I will be able to see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

The magic part that enables live reloading here isn't Docker, it's a Node tool called [nodemon](https://nodemon.io).  There are similar tools for other languages; for example, a live reloader is included as part of the [Spring Boot developer tools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html).

There's nothing intrinsic about Docker that makes live reloading possible.  In fact, it's counter to Docker's design: a Docker container usually runs on top of an immutable image that you have to rebuild when you have a code change.  That means you need extra Docker options to bypass Docker's normal filesystem isolation.

```sh
# Option A: use local node
sudo apt-get install nodejs
yarn install
yarn dev
```

```sh
# Option B: use Docker
sudo apt-get install docker.io # need to install something anyways
sudo             \ # easy to use Docker to root the host
  docker run     \
  --rm           \ # don't leak the container
  -v "$PWD:/app" \ # make local directory visible in application
  -w /app        \ # specify working directory
  -p 3000:3000   \ # make the application port visible
  node           \ # image to run
  sh -c          \ # need an explicit shell for multiple commands
  "yarn install && yarn run dev" # the thing we were actually trying to do
```

Where Docker is actually useful is deploying things.  If you don't need the bind mount or command override, then you can build and deploy any application in a consistent way (subject to the details in the per-application Dockerfile):

```sh
# Deploy using Docker
# (not a live-development setup; fully compatible with option A above)
sudo docker build -t me/myapp:20210626 .
sudo docker run -d -p 3000:3000 me/myapp:20212026
# (works identically with Express, React, Flask, Spring Boot, ...)
```

Comment: I feel like you can help me but you just read half of my question :(
I'm not using nodejs, I'm using java. I want to bind mount because my image will not be used to deploy, but to develop. So I can share this image with my developers and we're all using the same environment (java, tomcat, whatever I want to include in the image). We will later use another image to deploy, but that's outside of the scope.

Spring Boot Devtools was a good hint!! but still doesn't satisfy my needs, cause how can I run the project without compiling the code in the docker machine?

Comment: This is probably even more true with Java, since most things run inside the JVM and the app-server stack is _very_ established; there aren't usually native libraries or other complications like that which would require a complicated developer setup.  You need a JVM and Tomcat, and you can just install that; or you can install Docker, and build a custom image around that, and figure out how to get around permission and filesystem mapping issues.  You can get live reloading without Docker, and in fact Docker makes live reloading harder by introducing its filesystem isolation layer.

Comment: I was just thinking: If my app has to run in Tomcat, connect with MySQL, have an specific java version (that I agree with you it's not that hard to install it but swapping between java versions some times is tedious), what If I can solve all of this problems and provide an image to my Java Developers and they just need to care about coding and not connecting to external tools? But at the same time provide this live reloading that comes handy when coding. 
But I get your point maybe I'm overcomplicating things.